# Different front page for logged in users

Tags: 8

I want to show different front pages for different roles: Anonymous users should see www.domain.com\front, logged-in users should see  www.domain.com\dashboard.

There are two options I found so far:

1. **Using the [Front Page](https://www.drupal.org/project/front) module**
   I tried this but it doesn't work. I add the new front page locations to the right role. But the redirect doesn't happen.
2. **Making a custom module**
   Unfortunately (because of my limited knowledge on routes and controllers) the [article](https://andeers.com/2018/09/different-front-drupal/) I found doesn't give me enough information on how to make this module.

Can someone help me figuring out how to create a module based on the article? Point me in the right direction to learn how these routes and controllers work.

Or help me with another set up for a module that does this?

---

The answer of [Ziftman](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/19632/ziftman) is great. I changed it to my needs. I changed the if statement to check if the current page is the frontpage and not the path `/front`

Because I found out that this `\Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage()` does not always work. I used this to figure out if I'm on the frontpage:

```
$current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
$front_uri = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('page.front');
$front_alias = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath($front_uri);
$current_alias = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath($current_path);
$isFrontPage = \Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage() || $front_alias === $current_alias;
```

Then I not only wanted to see if the user is logged in but also specify it by role. So I used this to see if the current user has a certain role:

```
$hasRole1 = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id())->hasRole('role_name_1');
$hasRole2 = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id())->hasRole('role_name_2');
```

These combined make this if statement:

```
if($ifFrontPage && $hasRole1){
...
}
if($ifFrontPage && $hasRole2){
...
}
```

And finally I changed the local path to a domain change, because I needed it to check a role, and if the current user has a role. Then go to the dashboard on a different domain:

So this:

```
$path =  \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath('/dashboard');
$event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($path));
```

Became this is replaced by:

```
$domain_url =  'https://domain1.nl/dashboard';
$response = new TrustedRedirectResponse($domain_url);
$event->setResponse($response);
```

The complete if statements ended up like this:

```
if($ifFrontPage && $hasRole1){
    $domain_url =  'https://domain1.nl/dashboard';
    $response = new TrustedRedirectResponse($domain_url);
    $event->setResponse($response);
}
if($ifFrontPage && $hasRole2){
    $domain_url =  'https://domain2.nl/dashboard';
    $response = new TrustedRedirectResponse($domain_url);
    $event->setResponse($response);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is too broad for us: We cannot explain how to use that module, since you didn't say what exactly you don't understand in using it; we don't write code on demand, but we can say what is wrong in code you wrote, if the code is shown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a custom event subscriber.

With that event you are checking if the path is front and the user is logged in, then you perform the redirect.

Assuming your custom module name is '**custom**':

1- Register the even in the services file **custom/custom.services.yml**

```
services:
  custom.event_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\custom\EventSubscriber\MyCustomModuleSubscriber
    tags:
      - {name: event_subscriber}
```

2- Create the event subscriber at **custom/src/EventSubscriberMyCustomModuleSubscriber.php**:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class MyCustomModuleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function checkFrontRedirection(GetResponseEvent $event) {
  if (\Drupal::service('path.matcher')->matchPath('/front') && !\Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous()) {
    $path =  \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath('/dashboard');
    $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($path));
  }

}

/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
  $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = array('checkFrontRedirection');
  return $events;
 }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great. A minor comment is that at 2- you forgot a slash in the path to the event subscriber